# Why "<" character got replaced with unicode character in JSON response

Tags: json, api, facebook-graph-api

What is the reason behind replacement of "<" character with unicode character in FaceBook's Json API response?

security?? What kinda attack is possible, If the "<" character presents in the response.

Thanks
Bala

Comment: Any help on this will be highly appreciated.